# Add tabbed bar somewhere other than MainPage

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to know how I can put a tabbed bar on a specific page, since the user must first log in to enter the rewards part where the tabbed bar is located, but apparently I can only load it on the main page, how can I do that this tabbed bar is loaded on the rewards page and not on the mainpage, thanks in advance, I'm starting with xamarin

```
using System;
```

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ParkFitt
{
public partial class App : Application
{
Vistas.Menu objm = new Vistas.Menu();
public App()
{
InitializeComponent();

```
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        MainPage = new Recompensas(); //this is the tabbed page, but I want it not to load on the mainpage but on Reco
        
        
        }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6huL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua6bC.png)

In the second image is the Reco page where I want to add the tabbed page

Comment: It is preferable to insert images rather than link to them. Over time, link rot will mean that people will not be able to access the images and will not get the context of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your app starts

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

after the have logged in

```
MainPage = new MyTabbedPage();
```